# Plotting vectorized text documents in matplotlib?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have converted a whole heap of PDF documents to text and then compiled them to a dict, I know for a fact I have 3 distinct document types and I want to use Clustering to group them automatically:

```
dict_of_docs = {'document_1':'contents of document', 'document_2':'contents of document', 'document_3':'contents of document',...'document_100':'contents of document'}
```

Then, I vectored the values of my dictionary:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(dict_of_docs.values())
```

My output of X is something like this:

```
  (0, 768)  0.05895270500636258
  (0, 121)  0.11790541001272516
  (0, 1080) 0.05895270500636258
  (0, 87)   0.2114378682212116
  (0, 1458) 0.1195944498355368
  (0, 683)  0.0797296332236912
  (0, 1321) 0.12603709835806634
  (0, 630)  0.12603709835806634
  (0, 49)   0.12603709835806634
  (0, 750)  0.12603709835806634
  (0, 1749) 0.10626171032944469
  (0, 478)  0.12603709835806634
  (0, 1632) 0.14983692373373858
  (0, 177)  0.12603709835806634
  (0, 653)  0.0497440271723707
  (0, 1268) 0.13342186854440274
  (0, 1489) 0.07052056544031632
  (0, 72)   0.12603709835806634
  ...etc etc
```

Then, I converted them to an array, `X = X.toarray()`

I am at this stage now of trying to use my real data to scatter plot a cluster with matplotlib. From there I then want to use what I have learned with clustering to sort the documents. All the guides I have followed use made up data arrays, but they don't show how to go from real world data to something that can be used in the way they have demonstrated.

How do I get my array of vectorised data into a scatter plot?

Comment: Consider adding more details to your question. "It's not working" is does not give us a place to start! =)

Comment: Ok, well I guess I want to know how I go from vectorising my data, and what that means, and how I can display these vectorised documents with matplotlib.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I get my array of vectorised data into a scatter plot?

In few steps: clustering, dimensionality reduction, plotting and debugging.

#### Clustering:

We use K-Means to fit `X` (our *TF-IDF* vectorized dataset).

```py
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

NUMBER_OF_CLUSTERS = 3
km = KMeans(
    n_clusters=NUMBER_OF_CLUSTERS, 
    init='k-means++', 
    max_iter=500)
km.fit(X)
```

#### Dimensionality Reduction:

- *TF-IDF* is a matrix. We need 2~3 dimensions for plotting.
- We can apply PCA then plot the two most important principle components (the first two).

```py
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

# First: for every document we get its corresponding cluster
clusters = km.predict(X)

# We train the PCA on the dense version of the tf-idf. 
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
two_dim = pca.fit_transform(X.todense())

scatter_x = two_dim[:, 0] # first principle component
scatter_y = two_dim[:, 1] # second principle component
```

#### Plotting:

We plot every cluster with a pre-assigned colour.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(20,10)

# color map for NUMBER_OF_CLUSTERS we have
cmap = {0: 'green', 1: 'blue', 2: 'red'}

# group by clusters and scatter plot every cluster
# with a colour and a label
for group in np.unique(clusters):
    ix = np.where(clusters == group)
    ax.scatter(scatter_x[ix], scatter_y[ix], c=cmap[group], label=group)

ax.legend()
plt.xlabel("PCA 0")
plt.ylabel("PCA 1")
plt.show()
```

#### Debugger [source](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/kmeans-text-clustering/):

Print top 10 words in every cluster.

```py
order_centroids = km.cluster_centers_.argsort()[:, ::-1]

terms = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
for i in range(3):
    print("Cluster %d:" % i, end='')
    for ind in order_centroids[i, :10]:
        print(' %s' % terms[ind], end='')
    print()

# Cluster 0: com edu medical yeast know cancer does doctor subject lines
# Cluster 1: edu game games team baseball com year don pitcher writes
# Cluster 2: edu car com subject organization lines university writes article
```

[image]

Comment: I managed to get this to work with my data, thank you! My biggest issue is I don't understand 95% of it. I understand the idea behind it; we turn data into a plot point, we then assume the clustered plot points (vectors) are similar. However, a lot of the code I don't understand, could you reccommend a starting point? Should I just learn the packages individually, as in, learn matplotlib in general, then learn pandas, then learn KMeans?

Comment: I'm sorry if it was a bit vague, could you tell me the parts you don't understand? I can try and elaborate it more in the code. I would start with what is Kmeans, PCA and TF-IDF conceptually. The code/libraries are just tools :)

Comment: All good, I did a bit of reading up, and experimenting with your code and I've slowly figured out what each bit does. Awesome thanks!